# How do I query MarkLogic to determine cost of re-indexing?

Tags: marklogic

I have a multi-terabyte Production database (MarkLogic 9.0-8, RedHat) that I need to add 2 new element range indexes to. Before I can execute the change, I need to get an estimate of the number of documents that will be impacted by the re-index to ensure my maintenance window is sufficient to avoid performance impacts. Will the following code provide me with what I am needing?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("someTimestamp")));
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("someString")));
```

Comment: That should be accurate, as long as `someTimestamp` and `someString` only occur in the elements or paths for which you intend to add indexes.

Comment: I don't see how a word-query would be useful in this case. As of my unterstanding he wants to find out how many fragments (not documents) are affected by the new range indexes. Isn't a element-query searching for fragments with that element more useful then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `word-query` I'd rather count the fragments containing the elements of your two new element range indexes using a `element-query`.

```
xdmp:estimate(
  cts:search(fn:doc(), 
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("your-index-element"), (cts:and-query(())))
  )
)
```

Comment: if you are lazy and don't want to type as much, you could replace `(cts:and-query(()))` with `cts:true-query()`